# Booth multiplier vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I want to test different hardware integer multipliers. I have seen that one option is the Booth multiplier. The codes I have found take multiple cycles to get the result.

I would like to ask if implementing one cycle Booth multiplier is advantageous comparing with the combinational multiplier?
Which other multipliers can be implemented for performing the operation in cycle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is a fundamentally flawed question, from my understanding, Booth multipliers deliberatley take more than one clk cycle. As they are typically used for a heavily pipelined designs. [Please look at this paper as it may help your understanding](http://www.ijsrp.org/research-paper-0514/ijsrp-p2970.pdf)

Comment: It may be worth asking this in the [Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) as StackOverflow is more for code which you have not supplied.

Comment: Thank you @dyslexicgruffalo for your comment. Booth multiplier has different stages as add-shift multiplier, but they can be implemented performing one stage per every cycle, or a complete combinational circuit. For example this is a combinational Booth multiplier (https://www.slideshare.net/naseermna/seminar-on-digital-multiplierbooth-multiplier-using-vhdl). But I am not sure about the advantageous of this implementation